# Page recognition is delayed in UFT 12.5

Tags: hp-uft

I am able to identify browser but page identification is delayed in UFT 12.5. AS a result all the operations under the object are getting delayed.

Comment: Please add some code that shows what you have already tried.

Comment: HI James, 
Thanks for your reply. Actually i am trying to use google chrome v 47 and UFT 12.53. I have checked with compatibility version table and as per the table v47 version is supported by uft. But, still the page identification is delayed although browser identification is faster. Please suggest.

Comment: @suresh Please, show us the code you are using that is having trouble.  Without that, we cannot help you without guesswork.

Answer (score 0):

use implicit/explicit wait.. sample code

```
For I=1 to 100
    IF Page.exist(1) then
        exit for
    else
        wait (1)
    end if
next
```

Comment: Thanks Shailesh. But, i missed out to mention that the browser i used is google chrome v47. Kindly suggest.

Comment: 1.Browser.sync  and/or(u can use both) For I=1 to 100
    IF Object.exist(1) then
        exit for
    else
        wait (1)
    end if
next